# Add column with 0 or 1 to vector depending on vector values

Tags: r, if-statement, vector

I have a vector `vals` with values between 0 and 1 and I'd like to add another column `refs` to that vector.
The column should *only* contain values of 0 and 1 depending on a given variable `threshold`:

```
If vals[i] > threshold -> refs[i] = 1
If vals[i] <= threshold -> refs[i] = 0
```

What would be a simple approach?

Comment: A lot of function in R are vectorized, so you can try `+(vals > refs)`

Comment: @Maël But using prefix-`+` to coerce types is cryptic and relies on a side effect. I keep preaching to *please* write descriptive code instead; i.e. `as.integer(vals > refs)` (or, my favourite, even though it’s slower, `ifelse(vals > refs, 1L, 0L)`). Although it’s almost always better to forego the conversion entirely and use a logical vector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you want:

```
library(tidyverse)
vals <- c(1,2,3)
threshold <- 2
df <- data.frame(vals = vals)
df2 <- df %>% 
  mutate(refs = case_when(vals > threshold ~ 1,
                          vals <= threshold ~ 0))
df2
```

I put in a tangible example in the answer too.